# iOS 7 Displaying Status bar on Certain Views/Status Bar Cutting over View

Tags: ios, uikit, uistatusbar

I have an app where all of the views, except one, needs a status bar displayed on top. After spending time googling and searching here, I cannot find a solid answer that works. 
Right now, with `View controller-based status bar` appearance set to `YES`, and

```
 -(BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden
{
    return YES;
}
```

in my 'hidden status bar'  ModalViewController, the upper half of my Navigation Item is cut off.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/m2xc2.png

Currently, the rest of the app's view's **doesn't** have a status bar. Suggestions?

Comment: Um, you probably meant to set it to `YES` as you wanted precisely "view controller-based status bar", right ? And you definitely wanted to call `setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate` to be able to use the values other than default, as the documentation says.

Comment: @A-Live yes, I typo'ed that in the post. I called an update too. Still not working.

Comment: Make sure your `self.view.frame` is actually 0, not 20 points.

Comment: @SergiusGee the black bar is gone now, the status bar is shown, but I need it gone.

Comment: set `prefersStatusBarHidden` to return `YES` and call `setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate` in `ViewDidAppear` or `WillAppear` in that VC.

Comment: @SergiusGee while View controller-based status bar is set to YES? If so, its not working :(.